# For the function f(x)=1x, calculate (to 5 decimal places) f(a+h)−f(a)hwhere a= 5 and h = .5 h = 0.1

Tags: calculus

For the function f(x)=1/x, calculate (to 5 decimal places) f(a+h)−f(a)/h where a= 5 and

h = .5
h = 0.1

Do I sub the x in for the a? or do I place the whole function as 1/(a+h)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ will take the entire argument. You substitute in whatever is within the parens of $f$ for the $x$. Like the following:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f(a+h)=\frac{1}{a+h}$$

When $a=5$ and $h=0.5$ this is
$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{f(5.5)-f(5)}{0.5}=\frac{\frac{1}{5.5}-\frac{1}{5}}{0.5}$$

Hopefully you can take it from there.

This value gives us the slope of a secant line between $x=5$ and $x=5.5$ on the function. This will become significant when calculating derivatives via the limit method, where we calculate the slope of the line between at a single point!

Comment: so the solution should come to -2/55?

Comment: oh! i understand!

Comment: For $h=0.5$, almost. It comes to $-2/55$ (note the negative). The question asked for 5 decimal places, so I assume the desired answer is $-0.03636$

Comment: and then -2/255 for the other h

Comment: how is that written is decimal form?

Comment: No, the other one comes to a different number. Make sure you are substituting $h$ for 0.1 in both places! It appears at $f(x+h)$ (on top) and $h$ (on bottom)

Comment: ooooh! so -2/51

Comment: Yes! To convert this to a decimal (as you asked before) simply divide the top by the bottom $-2/55 = -2 \div 55 = -0.0392156...$